# Express JS Doesen't Work

Tags: node.js, express

I have a weird problem about Express.js

I have code like this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  res.send('Homepage');

});

app.get('/developers', function(req, res) {

  res.send('Developers');

});
```

When i go to my localhost, i see Homepage text, when i go to /developers page, i see developers text, but when i go to /developers/developer page, i can't see the result.

```
app.get('/developers/developer', function(req, res) {

  res.send('Developer test');

});
```

Why first and second routes work and why third route doesen't work?

Comment: The route looks fine. What do you get back when you access that URL?

Comment: It happens due to the fact '/developers' route gets matched first in your '/developers/developer' path. Placing '/developers/developer' route first and '/developers' next should help.

Comment: Actuallly i don't understand nothing from you :(. When i try to go /developers/developer i take this error on my browser "Cannot GET /developers/developer"

Comment: Your code worked perfectly fine for me, Without reodering

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the order of the route you have entered. app.get matches /developers first and follows the callback for it only. Try passing /developers/developer route above the /developers route. It will work.

> Like this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  res.send('Homepage');

});
app.get('/developers/developer', function(req, res) {

  res.send('Developer test');

});
app.get('/developers', function(req, res) {

  res.send('Developers');

});
```

Also, you can inline the /developers/developer within the /developers route

> index.js

```
var developer = require('developer');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

      res.send('Homepage');

});
app.use('/developers', developer());
```

> developer.js

```
var router = express.Router();
var developer = function() {
    var api = router();
    api.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Developers');
    });
    api.get('/developer', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Developer test');
    });
};
module.exports = developer;
```